# Not required output appear with asterisk in Matlab

Tags: matlab, output

I have a problem with my Matlab program output. Out of no where additional output answer appeared. Can anyone give a clue?

Here is the program:

```
for k = 2:N + 1
b = [r*u(1,k); zeros(M - 3,1); r*u(M + 1,k)] ...
+ r*(u(1:M - 1,k - 1) + u(3:M + 1,k - 1)) + r2*u(2:M,k - 1);
u(2:M,k) = trid(A,b);
```

Here is the output `u(2:M,k)` for :

```
1.0e+145 *

    2.9303
         0
   -2.9303
         0
    2.9303
         0
   -2.9303
         0
    2.9303
```

Comment: Can you give us a clue? What is wrong with the output? What were you expecting? What is you code trying to achieve?

Comment: The `1.0e+145 * ` only means that all values should be multiplied by that factor. It's instead of including it for all values. Are you sure your calculations are correct? `1.0e+145` is an extremely high number.

Comment: The answer should be between 0.1000 to 0.4000, and not e+145.Yes, is a high number. I trying to calculate temp using crank-nicolson method for PDE.

Comment: @user3165011 then your calculation is wrong...

Comment: Maybe your are right, i'm only using r=1, r2=2, M=10, N=10.

Comment: ...and the initial `u`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Robert P. this is how the result should be interpeted:

First the factor with which everything should be multiplied, followed with an asterics:

```
1.0e+145 *
```

In this case the factor is huge, `10^145`

Then follow the values, the factor applies to all of them

```
    2.9303
         0
   -2.9303
         0
    2.9303
         0
   -2.9303
         0
    2.9303
```

Note that a 0 here simply means that it is less than `0.0001*10^145`